Pointer-interceptor Error during android build
PS D:\refereevision> flutter build apk
Plugin pointer_interceptor:ios provides an implementation for pointer_interceptor_platform_interface and also references a default implementation for pointer_in
terceptor_ios, which is currently not supported. Ask the maintainers of pointer_interceptor to either remove the implementation via implements: pointer_interceptor_platform_interface or avoid referencing a default implementation via platforms: ios: default_package: pointer_interceptor_ios.
Target gen_dart_plugin_registrant failed: Error: Please resolve the plugin pubspec errors
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.


Process 'command 'D:\Softwares\flutter_windows_3.19.1-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            6.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS D:\refereevision>

Can you share your pubspec.yaml file? Seems like the issue is from one of your dependencies.

I also had this issue, seems the newest version of  pointer_interceptor caused this, try overriding it for now, while it's not fixed.
dependency_overrides:
  pointer_interceptor: ^0.10.1+1


this seems to be a valid answer.

update your dependencies
flutter pub upgrade

